able to install Azure monitor Agent installation without enabling any managed identity(system or user)
I am able to install Azure monitor Agent installation without enabling any managed identity(system or user) on a Virtual Machine through below powershell cmdlet
System-Assigned:
Set-AzVMExtension 
 -Name AzureMonitorWindowsAgent 
 -ExtensionType AzureMonitorWindowsAgent 
 -Publisher Microsoft.Azure.Monitor 
 -ResourceGroupName <resource-group-name>
 -VMName <virtual-machine-name> 
 -Location <location> 
 -TypeHandlerVersion <version-number> 
 -EnableAutomaticUpgrade $true 
 -SettingString '{"authentication":{"managedIdentity":{"identifier-name":"mi_res_id","identifier-value":"/subscriptions/<my-subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<my-resource-group>/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/<my-user-assigned-identity>"}}}

User-Assigned:
Set-AzVMExtension
 -Name AzureMonitorWindowsAgent
 -ExtensionType AzureMonitorWindowsAgent
 -Publisher Microsoft.Azure.Monitor 
 -ResourceGroupName <resource-group-name> 
 -VMName <virtual-machine-name> 
 -Location <location> 
 -TypeHandlerVersion <version-number> 
 -EnableAutomaticUpgrade $true

I have used both of the above powershell cmdlets on a set of VMs and did not assigned any system or user assigned managed identity but If I run the power shell script I am still able tp install the agent and no change is reflecting in identity section of VM.
Can someone help me understand the AMA installation process if I am getting in wrong direction.
I have built powershell script using below documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/azure-monitor-agent-manage?tabs=azure-portal


able to install Azure monitor Agent installation without enabling any managed identity(system or user)

If you are able to install the Azure Monitor Agent without enabling the System Managed Identity or User Managed Identity, it may be because you are logged in with a user account, not an identity authentication.
The Set-AzVMExtension command will work with user authentication as well.
In your case, make sure to check whether you are logged in with a user account by using Get-AzContext before executing the Set-AzVMExtension command.

To log in with an identity for installing the Agent on a VM, you need to enable the identity inside the VM, assign the role of Virtual Machine Contributor or Azure Connected Machine Resource Administrator, and log in with the identity using the commands below
Connect using a Managed  Identity ,Refer this link for authentication via managed identity in VM
Connect-AzAccount  -Identity
Set-AzContext -Subscription Subscription1

Connect using a User Managed  Identity Refer this Link for authentication via user managed identity in VM.
Connect-AzAccount -Identity -AccountId  $identity.ClientId

In my case, I installed the agent without enabling identity in VM and installed it using user authentication.
Set-AzVMExtension -Name AzureMonitorWindowsAgent -ExtensionType AzureMonitorWindowsAgent -Publisher Microsoft.Azure.Monitor -ResourceGroupName Venkat -VMName venkatvm -Location "East US" -TypeHandlerVersion "1.1" -EnableAutomaticUpgrade $true

Output:


What is the purpose of managed identity authentication on VM for creating Data Collection rules.

Managed Identity Authentication on a VM for creating Data Collection Rules in Azure provides a secure and streamlined way to authenticate and authorize the VM without requiring manual handling of credentials.

What if we trying to create Data collection rules and AMA installation through powershell, still we would be need to assign a managed Identity? May be I am getting confused

If you want to authenticate with Managed Identity, you must enable System Managed Identity on the VM and assign the necessary role; in this case, you will log in without specifying user credentials. If not, you need to login using your user credentials.

Hi @Srishtigarg, I hope this answered your issue. Let me know if there are still any issues.
